# Lista de produtos com carousel e flexbox

Tags: carousel, flexbox

Ola pessoal estou precisando de um auxilio para exibir uma lista de produtos responsivo que inicialmente sera 4 x 4 em telas de computadores (podendo ser alterado conforme a necessidade).
O código que eu tenho exibe os itens flex inline, mas eu preciso que ele exiba em colunas e quando o max-height for atingido a largura é aumentada a fim de criar o efeito desejado.

```js
$(".js-carousel").each(function(){
 var $carousel = $(this),
  $carouselContainer = $carousel.find(".js-carousel-container"),
  $carouselList = $carousel.find(".js-carousel-list"),
  $carouselItem = $carousel.find(".js-carousel-item"),
  $carouselButton = $carousel.find(".js-carousel-button"),
  setItemWidth = function(){
   $carouselList.removeAttr("style");
   var curWidth = $($carouselItem[0]).outerWidth() * $carouselItem.length;
   $carouselList.css("width", curWidth);
  },
  slide = function(){
   var $button = $(this),
    dir = $button.data("dir"),
    curPos = parseInt($carouselList.css("left")) || 0,
    moveto = 0,
    containerWidth = $carouselContainer.outerWidth(),
    listWidth = $carouselList.outerWidth(),
    before = (curPos + containerWidth),
    after = listWidth + (curPos - containerWidth);
   if(dir=="next"){
    moveto = (after < containerWidth) ? curPos - after : curPos - containerWidth;
   } else {
    moveto = (before >= 0) ? 0 : curPos + containerWidth;
   }
   
   
   $carouselList.animate({
    left: moveto
   });
  };
 $(window).resize(function(){
  setItemWidth();
 });
 setItemWidth();
 
 $carouselButton.on("click", slide);
});
```

```css
.carousel{
 padding: 0 30px;
}
.carousel__button--prev, .carousel__button--next{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
}
.carousel__button--prev{
 left: 0;
}
.carousel__button--next{
 right: 0;
}
.carousel__container {
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 200px;
}
.carousel__list{
 position: relative;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.carousel__list.unwrap{
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.carousel__item{
 flex: 1 0 250px;
/*  max-width: 300px; */
 height: 200px;
 background-color: #ccc;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 100px;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel js-carousel">
 <div class="carousel__container js-carousel-container">
  <div class="carousel__list js-carousel-list">
   <div class="carousel__item js-carousel-item">1</div>
   <div class="carousel__item js-carousel-item">2</div>
   <div class="carousel__item js-carousel-item">3</div>
   <div class="carousel__item js-carousel-item">4</div>
   <div class="carousel__item js-carousel-item">5</div>
   <div class="carousel__item js-carousel-item">6</div>
   <div class="carousel__item js-carousel-item">7</div>
   <div class="carousel__item js-carousel-item">8</div>
   <div class="carousel__item js-carousel-item">9</div>
   <div class="carousel__item js-carousel-item">10</div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="carousel__nav">
  <button class="carousel__button--prev js-carousel-button" data-dir="prev">&lt;</button>
  <button class="carousel__button--next js-carousel-button" data-dir="next">&gt;</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Caso o link do stack não execute corretamente vejam no CodePen: https://codepen.io/seleckis/pen/WwQgvx

Comment: Sulivan, vc quer que dependendo da altura da tela o seu slider fique com o número de colunas diferente? Seu pergunta ficou um pouco confusa... Na seria melhor delimitar o número de colunas pela largura max-width e não pela altura max-height...?